# Pycuda 2019.1, how to properly copy a gpuarray?

Tags: python, numpy, gpu, pycuda

Pycuda has a long standing bug in which it doesn't appear to preserve order or strides when copying ie:

```
import numpy as np
import pycuda.autoinit
from pycuda import gpuarray

np_array = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]], order="F")
gpu_array = gpuarray.to_gpu(np_array)

gpu_array_copy = gpu_array.copy()

# fails, order isn't the same. ravel also shows difference in order
assert(np.array_equal(gpu_array_copy.get(), np_array))
```

I'm wondering how to actually account for this?  Is the underlying memory actually the same? How can I make sure my copies actually, well, copy in pycuda?

Issues like [this](https://github.com/inducer/pycuda/issues/154) seem to indicate that strides can be fixed, but I don't know if that means the actual data underneath (the raw device memory) is actually configured correctly.

Answer (score 1):

For now, this is the solution I came up with (I'm still willing to accept better answers).

I've at least determined that the memory underneath during the copy is exactly the same. One thing I've done is tried to preserve both the stride and the flags, which for whatever reason aren't copied over.

Here is the function I've written that handles this:

```
def gpuarray_copy(array: gpuarray.GPUArray):
    array_copy = array.copy()
    array_copy.strides = array.strides
    array_copy.flags.f_contiguous = array.flags.f_contiguous
    array_copy.flags.c_contiguous = array.flags.c_contiguous
    array_copy.flags.forc = array.flags.forc
```

This at least solves the case of the host copy not being equal, and AFAIK should make the two gpuarrays exactly equal now.  This method may have other consequences, as I'm not sure why exactly inducer doesn't do this already, but I've yet to see any negative effects with respect to expected behavior.